# How can I call a dynamically selected SignalR client method from an IHubContext?

Tags: signalr

Is there any way to do something like this in SignalR:

```
public void CallClientMethod(string methodName, MyObject data)
{
    var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    ctx.Clients.All.methodName(data);

    // or alternatively
    ctx.Clients.All.CallClientMethod(methodName, data);
}
```

The above example illustrates the intent, rather than the actual mechanism - I want to determine the method to call at runtime, rather than compile time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void CallClientMethod(string methodName, MyObject data)
{
    var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    IClientProxy proxy = ctx.Clients.All;

    proxy.Invoke(methodName, data);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't method name be used without quotes? Right now all methods are called "methodName"

Comment: Omg! I was searching for this for soooo long! :) Thanks!!