# Call a method on a dynamic object by name

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm trying to create a "wrapper" around a dynamic object so I can keep method names on dynamic object matching the names of the methods in the wrapping class.

What I need to do is provide the helper a `dynamic` object, and the name of the method i want to call on it (via `[CallerMemberName]`), and the args for the call. I can't figure out how to invoke the call on the dynamic object. How can I do this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dyn = new ClassWithDynamicProperty();
        dyn.SendMessage("test");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ExampleDynamicClass
{
    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}

public class ClassWithDynamicProperty
{
    public ClassWithDynamicProperty()
    {
        MyDynObject = new ExampleDynamicClass();
    }

    public dynamic MyDynObject { get; set; }

    public void SendMessage(string theMessage)
    {
        //i want to replace this:
        MyDynObject.SendMessage(theMessage);
        //with this:
        DynamicHelper.CallDynamic(MyDynObject, new object[] { theMessage });
    }
}

public static class DynamicHelper
{
    public static void CallDynamic(dynamic source, object[] args, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    {
        //source.methodName(args); How can i invoke this?
    }
}
```

Comment: So why do you need dynamic then? You can use reflection isn't it?

Comment: This is just a sample. I'm using SignalR which has dynamic objects. I found a solution though that i'm about to post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it's not that hard after all. I didn't know if normal reflection would work with `dynamic` types. All resources I found for dynamic objects involved overriding `TryInvokeMember`, which wasn't an option. Here's missing code:

```
var method = ((object)dynamicObject).GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
method.Invoke(dynamicObject, args);
```

Comment: Assigning any type to a dynamic property doesn't make the object dynamic - that's why the reflection works here. Your solution does not work on `dynamic` objects - like these you get from IHubContext.

Here's how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632587/how-can-i-call-a-dynamically-selected-signalr-client-method-from-an-ihubcontext

`var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();`
`IClientProxy proxy = ctx.Clients.All;`
`proxy.Invoke(methodName, data);`