# Signalr: How to call a javascript function the name of which is defined at run time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I have googled this and been unable to find anything relevant. I want to call a javascript function in signalr the name of which is defined at runtime. Normally a function call would look like this

```
NotificationsHub.Clients.User(interestRegistration.UserName).functionName();
```

I would like to know if something like the following is possible:

```
string functionName = "myFunction";
NotificationsHub.Clients.User(interestRegistration.UserName).callDynamicFunction(functionName);
```

**The answer can be found in this stack overflow post: [How can I call a dynamically selected SignalR client method from an IHubContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632587/how-can-i-call-a-dynamically-selected-signalr-client-method-from-an-ihubcontext)**

Comment: this might answer your question (or at least guidance)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632587/how-can-i-call-a-dynamically-selected-signalr-client-method-from-an-ihubcontext

Answer (score 0):

You can access functions like array members if the function is in an object,

e.g.

```
var someObject = {
    theDynamicFunctionHere: function ()
    {
        alert("I am a dynamic function");
    }
};
```

Then you can call it by a variable name like this,

```
string functionName = "theDynamicFunctionHere";
someObject[functionName]();
```

Comment: Also if you are using MVC and Razor templates, you can build your javascript dynamically using razor templating to fill in the dynamic function name.

If you are using web forms, you could do the same thing by building a custom expression builder.

Comment: Then my follow up comment applies.